# Ionic icons are not shown in Android simulator

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, icons

Doing Meteor/Angular/Ionic tutorial, I got following problem:
[image]

Ionic icons are not displayed at Nexus 6 simulator Marshmallow screen.
Buttons are declared as follows:

```
        <button class="button button-clear button-icon button-positive
 icon ion-ios-camera-outline"></button>
```

I tried to add ion-android-camera class, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem today.

Comment: Not yet. It can be caused by incorrect font size (icons are actually from font), absense of font, or incorrect ionic version. Also, css class relates to ios, not Android. If you find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: A fix for this is described here: https://github.com/DAB0mB/angular-meteor-whatsapp/issues/12#issuecomment-217470054

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Thanks to Dave, the solution is as follows.
Reinstall packages:

```
meteor remove fourseven:scss
meteor remove meteoric:ionic-sass
meteor remove meteoric:ionicons-sass
meteor add fourseven:scss@2.0.0
meteor add meteoric:ionic-sass
meteor add meteoric:ionicons-sass
```

Let Meteor finish building. Add as the first line to every your `*.scss` file:

```
@import '***<path to your prj root like ../../>***.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';
```